# Automatically archive "DONE" entries regardless of keyword?

Tags: org-mode

I want to archive an entry automatically when its `todo` state gets marked as `done`.

The problem is that you can set up lots of different states that mean `done`.  So a function like this will only work if the done state is literally called `DONE`:

```
(defun channing/archive-when-done ()
    (when (equal (org-get-todo-state) "DONE") (org-archive-subtree-default)))
(add-hook 'org-after-todo-state-change-hook
    'channing/archive-when-done)
```

How can I detect if an entry is in the `done` state, regardless of the particular keyword?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can detect if an `org` entry is done with the (undocumented) predicate function **`org-entry-is-done-p`**.  It tests the current entry's `todo` keyword against `org-done-keywords`, which is also undocumented.  (I discovered these gems after reinventing this particular wheel symbol-for-symbol.)

For your purposes, you could rewrite your function as:

```
(defun channing/archive-when-done ()
  "Archive current entry if it is marked as DONE (see `org-done-keywords')."
  (when (org-entry-is-done-p)
    (org-archive-subtree-default)))
```

Comment: I think there are problems with this, items get moved but sometimes I get a line like this left in my todo.org: 

- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2016-02-13 Sat 22:32]
which should be with the moved item.

Comment: @ChanningWalton: hmm, well, for the narrow purposes of the question (how to detect if entry is `done`), then `org-entry-is-done-p` is what you need.  As for the broader question of the extra material left in your org file, that's a bug in your archive functionality, unfortunately.  Good luck tracking it down!

Comment: It seems I have some entertainment ahead of me!

Comment: @ChanningWalton: most certainly!  The org innards are <cough> <cough> baroque, so I don't envy you the task.