# A read list in Org

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to have an Org file with the following structure

```
* Books
** Fantasy
*** TOREAD Fantasy Book 1
*** READING Fantasy Book 2
*** TOREAD Fantasy Book 3

** Comedy
*** TOREAD Comedy Book 1

* Articles
** Science
*** TOREAD Article 1


* Archive
** Books
*** Fantasy
**** READ Fantasy Book X
**** WONTREAD Fantasy Book X
*** Comedy
** Articles
*** Science
```

In words, some hierarchy, and an archived version of that hierarchy with items flagged as done (here READ and WONTREAD).  The goal is for the archiving to be done automagically when flagging the item as done.

As an example: If `Fantasy Book 2` were to be set as `READ`, it would fall under `Archive>Books>Fantasy`, at the bottom of it.

**Question:**  Is this doable?  Is this legal?

My org-foo is in its infancy, and help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Better answer: select DONE regardless particular keyword, and answer to your question: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19995/automatically-archive-done-entries-regardless-of-keyword

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143959/keeping-the-context-when-archiving-in-emacs-org-mode.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `org-after-todo-state-change-hook`, which

> Hook which is run after the state of a TODO item was changed.
>   The new state (a string with a TODO keyword, or nil) is available in the
>   Lisp variable ‘org-state’.

```
(add-hook 'org-after-todo-state-change-hook 'konstantin/org-archive-when-done)
```

And the function to be hooked is the `konstantin/org-archive-when-done`

```
(defun konstantin/org-archive-when-done ()
  "Archive item when TODO state changed to DONE"
  (if (member org-state '("DONE" "DELEGATED"))
      (org-archive-subtree)
    ()))
```

Here you can see list of stages like `("DONE" "DELEGATED")`, which means to be like DONE.  In your case it is `("READ" "WONTREAD")`.

For automatically load this function, put its into `init.el`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I believe the focus of my question is elsewhere: I wonder how to make `org-archive-subtree` work as I asked, that is, putting the item on the Archive sub tree in the file, at the same hierarchical entry, at the end of it.  Did I miss that?

Comment: @Michaël Where archived items go is decided by `org-archive-location`.  Try setting it to `"::* Archive"`

Comment: @erikstokes: Thanks for your comment!  However, I feel this is not the important part again: the archived item should fall *within the same tree* on the Archived header.  Cheers!

Comment: @Michaël That can also be done, but is more than a comment.  Try asking a separate question.

Comment: @erikstokes : but this *is* my question!  :-)

Comment: @Michaël I think you're asking two questions here: 1) How do I automatically archive entries on marking them DONE and 2) How to preserve the outline structure when archiving.

Comment: @erikstokes: We should not argue on the intent here, the question asks for the archiving to be done in a precise way as is.  I know about `org-archive-subtree`, as any introductory text on Org would present it.  Thanks for your input!